# Is there a way to get ip addresses/domain names from dns?

Tags: dns, ip

What I am trying to do is get a list of ip addresses/domain names from the dns server(like 8.8.8.8 or 8.8.4.4 or so) my pc uses to surf the net. How can I do this?


The reason I need this is that I want to create a button using python that opens a random web site on click.

Answer (score 0):

Even if that is possible, there is the problem that most recorts are not web-servers, so your approach would not work.